# iam returning data in json_encode format and trying log the output in ajax, but getting parse error.?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

---

My Model-- iam getting data from Mysql database and returning it to controller

```
public function getCharges(){
    $where = "charge_type  = 'variable';
    $data = $this->read('charges',$where);
    return $data;
}
```

---

My Controller -- Here iam encoding the data in the json format to ajax

```
if (isset($_POST['method']) &&  $_POST['method'] == 'getCharges'){
     $this->load->model('Apiweb_m');
     $data = $this->Apiweb_m->getCharges();
     echo json_encode($data);
}
```

---

My AJAX

```
var method = "getCharges";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'method='+method,
    url : api_url+"apiweb",
   /* dataType: "json",*/
    success:function(msg){
        var data =  $.parseJSON(msg);
        console.log(data);// here iam getting Parse error 
    },
    error:function(Xhr, status, error){
        console.log(Xhr);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
    }
```

Comment: Please add sample ajax response which you are getting, Additionally if it response is correct then `contentType: 'application/json'` add in request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set dataType ajax property json.Hope you will do it like that.

```
var method = "getCharges";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'method='+method,
    url : api_url+"apiweb",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(msg){
        var data =  $.parseJSON(msg);
        console.log(data);// here iam getting Parse error 
    },
    error:function(Xhr, status, error){
        console.log(Xhr);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change function in model to :

```
public function getCharges(){
    $where = "charge_type  = 'variable'";
    $data = $this->read('charges',$where);
    return $data;
}
```

and ajax:

```
var method = "getCharges";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {method:method},
    url : api_url+"apiweb",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(msg){
        var data =  $.parseJSON(msg);
        console.log(data);// here iam getting Parse error 
    },
    error:function(Xhr, status, error){
        console.log(Xhr);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
    }
```